# AggregateResult in Map

Tags: apex, map, aggregateresult

I am getting the following error message but i dont know what i am doing wrong. I am trying to create a Map with AggregateResult. I am getting following error message.

> Incompatible key type Object for Map

```
List<AggregateResult> lstShiftOfFund = [SELECT Category_shifted_Into__c catShift,
                                        SUM(How_much_total_reallocated__c)totVal                                                                     
                                        FROM Shift_Funds_Into_This_Category__c
                                        WHERE Funds__c IN :shiftFunSet
                                        GROUP BY Category_shifted_Into__c ];

Map<String,Decimal> mapShiftofFund = new Map<String,Decimal>();


for(AggregateResult aggResult : lstShiftOfFund)
{
mapShiftofFund.put(aggResult.get('catShift'), aggResult.get('totVal'));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to typecast the type of object. like this

```
for(AggregateResult aggResult : lstShiftOfFund)
{
  mapShiftofFund.put((String)aggResult.get('catShift'), (Decimal)aggResult.get('totVal'));
}
```